# WPF - ListView Selection style

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I'm using a Listview Control with two columns, one is text and one has a rectangle init.
When an Item is selected I want the content of the item to be white (both the text in column 1 and the rectangle in column 2) but what happens is that only the text is getting white.

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Selection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style x:Key="@ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType='{x:Type ListViewItem}'>
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="Content" TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Columns="{TemplateBinding GridView.ColumnCollection}" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White" TargetName="Content" />
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" TargetName="Bd"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd"
                                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
                                </MultiTrigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="@TextCellTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="@TrubleCellTemplate">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Style="{DynamicResource @ListView}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource @ListViewItemStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="40" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TextCellTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="131" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource @TrubleCellTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

This is the code behind:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person> {new Person {Name = "Ashton"}};
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a DataTrigger for IsSelected to your @TrubleCellTemplate like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="@TrubleCellTemplate">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="Black"></Rectangle>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```